# Why can't I install python-Scrapy?

Tags: python, linux, scrapy

I am a novice Vagrant user and have a trusty64 box up. I do:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

[Then this happens.](https://gist.github.com/chimmel/6a123b87462dbb28f770e9f04b9a149a)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/http/request/form.py", line 11, in <module>
    import lxml.html
ImportError: No module named lxml.html`
```

What on earth do I do here? First I tried installing via pip3 but then read that Twisted is in 2. How do I just get this right?

UPDATE:::
@Paula: So I destroyed and initialized it with

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
sudo pip install Scrapy
```

and on SCRAPY install I get THIS printed at me more than once:

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Compile failed: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 4
```

How about that?

Comment: it means you don't have the underlying libxml C libraries. You probably need `apt-get install lxml` and `apt-get install lxml-dev` (i'm not sure the exact name, I usually use Redhat based distros)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this first.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev
```

As @Cfreak says you have unmet library dependencies.